# Can I safely git/commit/push or rsync a file being currently written by tee without breaking any pipe?

Tags: rsync, pipe, git, scp, tee

I have a pipe working for several days and writing some scientific results at a very low rate (a block of about 20 lines once an hour); most of the time, nothing is written. The file is written by `tee`.

I would like to get the new results every day without disturbing the process; of course I don't want to break the pipe.

Can I create a private repository with this file in order to commit the (currently being written) file in order to look at the new results from my phone or whatever?

If I commit and push, could the pipe be broken in some way?

**EDIT**: other idea, can I `rsync` or `scp` the file (from my phone) in order to consult new results?

Comment: Why don't you just set up a second pipe using `mkfifo`, `cat` etc. with some example data, and try it?

Comment: @dirkt Because if there was a race condition, as luck would have it, you might well never see any corruption in your test, even though it might happen on the real data.

Comment: I tried with `scp` and it seems to work nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Git does nothing but read from the file. This will definitely not break the pipe. You can even create a git repository for a read-only directory and commit read-only files. As long as you're only adding and committing stuff, rather than doing anything that checks something out or modifies the working directory, the only place where Git needs to write is inside the Git directory (`.git` by default but you can put it somewhere else with `git --git-dir=…`).

If you're really worried you can confirm this by looking at the Git source code. Or by looking at what git does to commit a file…

```
strace -o commit.strace -f git commit -m wibble foo
```

You'll see only `lstat` and `open(…, O_RDONLY)` calls on `foo`.

What may fail is the `git add` action. If the process happens to be writing to the file while Git is reading it, Git may notice that the file has changed and give up. This doesn't affect the source file in any case: `git add myfile` should do nothing if it fails, but even if Git is somehow buggy and doesn't recover properly, it'll only affect the Git index, not the data file which Git only ever opens read-only. I think the error message would be [“confused by unstable object source data”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423827/git-says-fatal-confused-by-unstable-object-source-data), but I haven't checked, there may be some other check on the size that triggers first. Given your data rate, if `git add` fails, pause for a second and try again.